# Search ListView using SearchView and SQLite Database and Fragments Trouble

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, searchview

I am having issues with the SearchView in my project. Here is the search components of the fragment:

```
    public class SupplementFragment extends Fragment implements . AddDialog.AddDialogListener
{
// declare java references
private TextView msgTextView;
private Button btnAdd;
private ListView lvSupplements;
private DatabaseHandler dbh;
private MyCursorAdapter adapter;


private SearchView svSearchSupp;
//SearchManager searchManager;

// reference to hold fragment
private SupplementFragment frag;

//DatabaseHandler dataBase;

// class method to create and return object of the fragment
public static SupplementFragment newInstance() {

    SupplementFragment fragment = new SupplementFragment();
    return fragment;
}

// default constructor
public SupplementFragment(){}

// Called to create the view hierarchy associated with the fragment.
// container from Activity holding the fragment.
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // inflate the xml layout file into the fragment, save the rootview
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.supplement_frag, container, false);

    // test the supplement table
    DatabaseTest.populateSupplementTable(this.getContext());


    // use the rootView and findViewById to create Java object tied to the resource
    msgTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.msgTextView);
    msgTextView.setText("Supplement Frag Example");
    btnAdd = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    lvSupplements = rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvSupplements);
    lvSupplements.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    // search controls
    svSearchSupp = rootView.findViewById(R.id.svSearchSupp);
    setupSearchView();

    // create the database handler object
    dbh = new DatabaseHandler(this.getContext());
   // Cursor c = dbh.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(DatabaseHandler.TABLE_SUPPLEMENT, null);

    // create and set the cursorAdapter to the business listView
    adapter = createMyCursorAdapter();
    lvSupplements.setAdapter(adapter);
    // use getActivity to get reference to the Activity if needed
    MainActivity ma = (MainActivity)getActivity();

    svSearchSupp.setOnQueryTextListener(new 
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            try
            {
                //adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                getSupplements(newText);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

      Log.i("Fragment", "Supplement onCreateView");

    return rootView;
}
```

I also have these two methods that are created for search function (In the same fragment) :

```
private void getSupplements(String searchTerm) throws Exception {

    //dbh.retrieve(searchTerm);
    SupplementInfo s = null;
    Cursor c = dbh.retrieve(searchTerm);
    adapter.getFilter().filter(searchTerm);
    adapter.swapCursor(dbh.getAllSupplementObjects());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

private void setupSearchView() {
    //svSearchSupp.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    //svSearchSupp.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    //svSearchSupp.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    svSearchSupp.setQueryHint("Search...");
}
```

Here is the 'retrieve' method from my DatabaseHandler class:

```
    public Cursor retrieve(String searchTerm) {

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String [] columns = {DatabaseHandler.COL_ID, DatabaseHandler.COL_NAME, DatabaseHandler.COL_INFO};
    Cursor c = null;

    if(searchTerm != null && searchTerm.length() > 0) {

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHandler.TABLE_SUPPLEMENT + " WHERE " + DatabaseHandler.COL_NAME +
                " LIKE '%" + searchTerm + "%'"; //
        c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

    }
    c = db.query(DatabaseHandler.TABLE_SUPPLEMENT, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
   //  c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE_SUPPLEMENTS", null);
    db.close();
    return c;
}
```

So, now that I think I've enough code for you to consume. The issue is when I click the SearchView in the fragment and begin to type, the ListView doesn't change or doesn't move. I also don't get any errors in the LogCat to know what the issue may be. Any help would be appreciated, I apologize if this is unclear in anyway, I can provide any other details.

Comment: @psink thanks for the info, do I have to call the filterQueryProvider as well?

Comment: Well i created it like this::: ---

           private FilterQueryProvider filterQueryProvider = new FilterQueryProvider() {
        @Override
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            return dbh.getAllSupplementObjects();
        }
    };

is the return statement correct?

Comment: I created and kept it as return NULL; I called    
        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText); inside the onQueryTextChange
still doesn't work.

Comment: Would you be able to provide me with an example? I created Cursor c = dbh.getAllSupplementObjects(); and then had it return c; - this still didn't result in anything.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help me out. Unfortunately I might just not be following (still learning android). The only Cursor that contains the rows would be the "MyCursorAdapter" class (which has the newView and bindView), or the "dbh.getAllSupplementObjects();" that is in my DatabaseHandler class, which gets all the supplement objects in the ListView.

Comment: I saw the comment, I have to give it a try when I get home from work. I'm thinking I'm just returning the Cursor wrong and trying to think how I set it.

Comment: must be returned like "Cursor cursor = adapter(constraint) return cursor; OR Cursor cursor = // whatever my list is hooked to with rows(constraint) return cursor;

Comment: yes I have the method written in my Databasehandler class.I'll give it a shot when I get home in a few hours and let you know.

Comment: also - if I understand you right? You said to copy / paste my sample code: "Cursor cursor = adapter(constraint)" /*or the other example* to the onCreateView of my Fragment? not inside the FilterQueryProvider filterQueryProvider = new ..... method?

Comment: */ refer to my code above for onCreateView

Comment: OH okay sorry. - I will do that and let you know. Thanks

Comment: currently working on this - I have red lines beneath the 
    "ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null)," line. Everything else isn't throwing an error (Yet) I also added this to my Fragment Class since I am using fragments.. not Main activity.

Comment: allso the "getContentResolver() needed a method..

Comment: I did that and it did not run. the app immediately crashes if I add your code to the Activity#onCreate

Comment: `com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream` is the logcat, I've never had to debug before

Comment: here is the code from the logcat that is in red when the app initially crashes

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mrf1nEfc

Comment: apparently my error has to do with access the "Contacts" of the phone, for some reason and I do not need that. I simply need my searchView to work. This has become incredibly more complicated than it should be.

Comment: you have 28 lines of full, working code... do you call it complicated?

Comment: no need for disrespect man, I'm still learning this. The error - to me - is a complicated issue, and the searchview issue - to me - is a complicated issue.

Comment: if the code that you provided me with was working properly, would it have fixed my searchView, or would it have just been an example as to how it should work?